# Firefox form analyzer plugin

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to know if there is any firefox html form analyzer or for any other browser.
Form analyzer is a tool that once you submit a POST form or any other type of form, will tell you the fields submitted together with their value. A good analyzer can by located in the following address

```
http://www.webbotsspidersscreenscrapers.com/form_analyzer.php?term=hello&sort=up
```

but the problem with that analyzer is that the information is posted to this address. What I want to do is to post the data on my server and see if the data works correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Would HttpFox suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [Live HTTP Headers Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) and [Firebug Network Analysis functionality](http://getfirebug.com/network). They will let you analyze any form submitted from within Firefox.